# CLS hitting on performance

Tags: c++, time-complexity

This code prints the desired no(4 here) of perfect numbers. It's an old code of mine and checks up every number whether it's perfect or not. It runs normally and finishes in 6-ish seconds, but if I put a cls before checking every number it takes a big hit(about 100 secs). Please tell me the theory behind it(why multiple cls takes a hit on performance).

**No normie answers like "Dude obviously it takes a hit, it's refreshing the screen every time."**

PS- I know the better way is not to check perfect numbers but to generate them.(By Euclid-Euler theorem)

IDE- DevC++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int choice, quan, i, a[50], number;
string schoice;

void startgame()
{
    choice = 3;
    quan = 4;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Hey guys, today we are gonna print different types of numbers\n";
    cout << "\nFollowing are some of the special numbers found in the known observable little universe of ours:- \n";
    cout << "\n1. Prime numbers\n2. Square numbers\n3. Perfect Numbers\n\n";
    cout << "Which ones do you wanna see?\n";
    //cin >> choice;
    cout << "\nCool! How many of them do you wanna see?\n";
    //cin >> quan;
}
void perfect()
{
    if (choice == 3)
    {
        int j = 0, y = 0, f = 0, number = 2;
        do
        {
            //This is the cls in question
            //system("cls");
            cout << "The number under inspection: " << number << "\n";
            f = 0;
            for (i = (number - 1); i >= 1; i--)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    f = f + i;
                }
            }

            if (f == number)
            {
                //cout<<number<<", ";
                a[j] = number;
                j = j + 1;
                y = y + 1;
            }
            number++;
        }
        while (y < quan);
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nHere are your " << quan << " perfect numbers starting from 1:-\n";
        j = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < quan; i++)
        {
            cout << a[i];
            if (j != quan)
            {
                cout << ", ";
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    do
    {
        startgame();
        perfect();
        cout << "\n\nReturn to Main menu?(Y/N)\n";
        schoice = "N";
        //cin >> schoice;
    }
    while (schoice == "Y");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if I put a cls before checking every number` purpose?

Comment: Sir, actually I just wanted the output to be more elegant I guess. Sorry that must've sounded foolish, but I am kinda new to this. Thnx for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run system("cls"), you create a new process, and you do that every time you pick a new number for inspection.
Creating a process is an expensive operation, and more importantly you don't need it, if all you want is to update current number on screen.
It is sufficient to write

```
cout << "The number under inspection: " << number << "\r";
```

`cout.flush();`

The first line will output text and return cursor to the beginning of the same line.
The second line will make sure all the above does show up on the display.
Note: this is also slow operation, so you would probably want to rate limit it.
I suggest you output this for every 1 number in 1000 or so.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I researched after your answer and tried to understand the difference between /n /r etc but don't know what exactly flush do. Please elaborate on that. The code runs fine even without the flush line. So what betterment it brings. Thanks again.

Comment: flush() call forces the output from internal buffer to the device. It may or may not be necessary, depending on the OS environment you have. It is likely necessary if your console output is buffered and not flashed by default with a \r character. This is for example the case with most Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Windows CreateProcess() is quite expensive, much more expensive than Unix fork(). Moreover, system("cls") is an inefficient, non-portable hack. You can't use it in non-windows systems. You can use ncurses library that supports console manipulation.

For Windows, via Console API:

```
void clear() {
    COORD topLeft  = { 0, 0 };
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;
    DWORD written;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        console, ' ', screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        console, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
        screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'm not really sure how much I take from this but know I know what to research. This is way profound and intriguing for me, thanks!!